# Easy way to find out preferred search engine terms for topic?

Tags: search-engines

Say, find out whether people search for "how to kill gorillas" or "guide to gorilla killing". This could be stupendously helpful for deciding on a web page title.

I suppose you could go and do search result number comparisons yourself, but are there any better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also the [Google keyword tool](https://adwords.google.co.uk/select/KeywordToolExternal). It's good because it also gives traffic stats for alternative terms.

Comment: Looks somewhat promising.

Comment: American version: https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends) to display a graph comparison of popularity. The timeline is pretty useful for analyzing spikes as well.

The topics have to be something common though, as google doesn't have many searches at all for how to kill gorillas.

Comment: Hmmm... not perfect, but interesting.